# Print to file in c++

Tags: c++, printing

I have to print some objects fields to a file. I overloaded `operator<<`, and I have a method "`draw`" that uses it.

How can I print it to file?

```
ostream& operator <<(ostream& out, const Widget& obj)
{
    int* colors2 = new int[3];
    colors2 = obj.getbackgroundColor().getColor();
    int* colors = new int[3];
    colors = obj.getTextColor().getColor();
    out << "[position (" << obj.getPosition().getX() << ","
    << obj.getPosition().getY() << ") ,";
    out << "width (" << obj.getWidth() << ") ";
    out << "height (" << obj.getHeight() << ") ,";
    out << "text (" << obj.getText() << ") ,";
    out << "colors (" << colors[0] << "," << colors[1] << "," << colors[2]
    << ") ,";
    out << "background colors(" << colors2[0] << "," << colors2[1] << ","
    << colors2[2] << ") ,";
    delete[] colors;
    delete[] colors2;
    return out;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would want to use C++ ofstream (output file stream). You need to create an ofstream object, open the file you want to write to, and then you could use the default << operator already defined for output file stream in order to print to the file.

Take a look at the C++ documentation for `ofstream`; that should help you get a better understanding of file I/O.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have `operator<<()` overloaded, use it:

```
std::ofstream my_file("data.s");
Widget w;
my_file << w;
```

Answer (score 0):

The easy way to do this:

```
void draw(const std::string & filename)
{
    std::ofstream file(filename.c_str()); //open a file for writing. 
                                          //Can use filename directly on newer compilers
    file << wiget1; //use the << operator overload
    file << wiget2; 
    ...
}
```

The above version will open, overwrite, and close `filename` for every call to `draw`. This may not be what you want if you plan on having multiple calls to `draw` and the output of all those `draw`s in the same file.

Rather than passing in the file name and opening `file`, you can open `file` elsewhere and pass it in to `draw`. This will allow multiple calls to `draw` for the same file.

Elsewhere:

```
std::ofstream file(filename.c_str());
```

new Draw:

```
void draw(std::ofstream & file)
{
    file << wiget1; //use the << operator overload
    file << wiget2; 
    ...
}
```